# Can't login to my Laravel project after cloned it from git

Tags: laravel, jwt

I recentley finished a little [project in git](https://github.com/roybarak80/Laravel-Social-App) 
I've used JWT Auth and for some reason the token isn't saved and therefore - i always get kicked to home page.

Here are the steps i've done when i cloned it:

1. clone from https://github.com/roybarak80/Laravel-Social-App.git
2. create DB
3. import DB.sql from root folder
4. update .env file with your db credetials (rename .env.samlpe to .env)
5. run composer update
6. run npm install
7. run php artisan key:generate
8. run php artisan config:cache
9. run php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"

It seems like users can't authenticate in the middleware - i put a break point in the constructor of the user's profile page and it seems that the problem is there

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{

   $this->middleware('jwt.auth'); // that's what make the problem
}

public function addNewFriend(Request $request)
{
    $newFriendId = $request->all()[0];
    $userId = $request->user()->id;
    User::addFriend($userId, $newFriendId);

}

public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{

    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {

            return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'user not found!');
        }
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
        return response()->json(['token expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
        return response()->json(['token Invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTExecption $e) {
        return response()->json(['token absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }

    $loggedUserData = self::setLoggedUserData($user);
    return response()->json(compact('loggedUserData'));
}

public function setLoggedUserData($loggedUser)
{
    $userId = Auth::id();

    $site_all_users = User::getAllUsersWithFriendsIndication($userId);

    $userHobbies = User::getUserHobbies($userId);

    $potentialFriends = User::getPotentialFriends($userId);

    $friendsBirthDays = User::getFriendsBirthDaysDates($userId);

    $usersFriends = User::getAllUserFriends($userId);

    $upComingBirthDays = User::getUpComingBirthDays();

    $loggedUser['userHobbies'] = json_encode($userHobbies);
    $loggedUser['potentialFriends'] = json_encode($potentialFriends);
    $loggedUser['friendsBirthDays'] = json_encode($friendsBirthDays);
    $loggedUser['site_all_users'] = json_encode($site_all_users);
    $loggedUser['usersFriends'] = json_encode($usersFriends);
    $loggedUser['upComingBirthDays'] = json_encode($upComingBirthDays);

    return $loggedUser;
}


}
```

Comment: I think you've made a couple of mistakes here, but I think firstly you should at the docs and maybe follow them again, I notice you are on version 1.0.0 so it has limited information, but for example, I think your middleware pointer is incorrect and a couple of things in your step by step to reproduce is missing a bunch of things: please see https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Comment: Also not sure if this is by design, but your /register route is using a text input rather than a password one

Comment: Thanks - after spends some time with it - it was the order of the project configuration - as you'll see in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Got it - it was the wrong order of the project batch commands, here is the correct order:

1. git clone https://github.com/roybarak80/Laravel-Social-App.git
2. create DB
3. import DB.sql from root folder
4. update .env file with your db credetials (rename .env.samlpe to .env)
5. run 
   composer update
   run npm install
6. run 
   php artisan key:generate
   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
   php artisan jwt:secret